# Deprecating Inventory Total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing an inventory availability analysis using SQL, trying to calculate a running total for inventory levels... see below

Available Qty = 14

I am trying add and calculate the Allocate column and have it deprecate by AvailQty - OrderQty. I have everything except the Allocate column. I am only using the AvailQty as a visual, it will not be used in the final output

| SO Number | Material | OrderQty | Order Value | AvailQty | Allocate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15001 | 12345 | 10 | 4473.60 | 14 | 10 |
| 15002 | 12345 | 10 | 4473.60 | 14 | 4 |
| 15003 | 12345 | 9 | 4026.24 | 14 | 0 |

Thanks so much for the response.  I think that I may have missed something.  When I run the query on Material, I get the expected results, but when I run wide open, the Allocate column doesn't compute, I THINK that it is because of the way I am sorting by OrderValue Highest to Lowest, but not 100% sure.

Running By Material Number

| SO Number | Material | OrderQty | Order Value | AvailQty | Allocate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15001 | 12345 | 27 | 4474.00 | 9 | 9 |
| 15002 | 12345 | 11 | 4473.60 | 9 | 0 |
| 15003 | 12345 | 6 | 4026.24 | 9 | 0 |

Now a subset of running wide open

| SO Number | Material | OrderQty | Order Value | AvailQty | Allocate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15001 | 12345 | 27 | 4474.00 | 9 | 0 |
| 15255 | 21769 | 8 | 4473.80 | 123 | 0 |
| 15002 | 12345 | 11 | 4473.60 | 9 | 0 |
| 15003 | 12345 | 6 | 4026.24 | 9 | 0 |
| 15223 | 45885 | 80 | 2365.00 | 5680 | 80 |

Like I said, I think that it is because of the way it is ordering the data when run wide open vs. filtering on Material, but I'm not 100% sure.  Is there a way to this without filtering on Material?  I probably should have mentioned this earlier, sorry for that.

Comment: I added some extra lines, to make you table look OK, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71791344/revisions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `sum() over(order by ..)` to generate a running total of the total OrderQty. `Case` expression to check `AvailQty` against the running total and calculate the `Allocate` quantity

```
select *, 
       Allocate = case when AvailQty >= sum(OrderQty) over (order by OrderVal desc, 
                                                                     SONumber)
                       then OrderQty
                       when AvailQty - sum(OrderQty) over (order by OrderVal desc, 
                                                                    SONumber) 
                                     + OrderQty > 0
                       then AvailQty - sum(OrderQty) over (order by OrderVal desc, 
                                                                    SONumber) 
                                     + OrderQty
                       else 0
                       end
from   SalesOrder
order by OrderVal desc, SONumber;
```

Comment: Had to use the Partition by Material to get it to do what I wanted.  Thanks again!